# Similar to how IntelliJ shows you the uncommitted changes in blue, is there a similar way to show the last commit changes instead?

Tags: intellij-idea

So just like how intellij shows you uncommitted changes in this format [Uncomitted change](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvffY.png)

Is there a way to show last commit changes in a similar way? i know show history option exist but then clicking on every method to see history is kind of cumbersome.If a plugin exist for it then that would also be very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use "[Annotate](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/investigate-changes.html#annotate)" feature in order to see when changes were committed.

Also you may find this and all related tickets convenient, so please feel free to vote:
https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-190536